# How to exit as Sub in Java

Tags: java, android

In VB you would create this code:

```
Sub doitnow()
dim a = 1
   for a = 1 to 45
    if a = 5
      exit sub
    end if
    a = a +1
   next a
end sub
```

In Java how do you exit early? I have a program with settings and diferent ways to enter the program and if you enter without having the settings done, I wish to stop the activity and send them to the settings activity.

Currently I have:

```
try {
  Ls = new LoadSettings(Add.this);
  gs = new GlobalSubs();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Intent c = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
  finish();
  startActivity(c);
}
```

But the same activity continues and does not stop creating a force stop error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exit a function early in Java, simply place `return` on the line where you want to exit:

```
for (int a = 1 ; a != 45 ; a++) {
    if (a == 5) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: but the function is a void

Comment: @John That's right, that's why there is no expression following `return` as in `return 123;`, just a `return` by itself.

Comment: for some reason i placed return null and it worked. ill do some more looking i have done something stuppid. thanks

Comment: it was a protected void doInBackground(String... params)

Comment: @John `doInBackground` can have a `Void` return parameter, but not `void`. It's subtly different, which is why `return null;` is what you need in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `Exit Sub` in Java is `return`. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17):

> A return statement returns control to the invoker of a method

For `void` methods simply use `return` on its own.